# Know which Table changed in global realmChangeListener

Tags: java, android, realm

I am using Realm as database for my app.

I have few tables in my database say- Table1, Table2, Table3, Table4 and Table5.

I have same number of Activities as tables, each of which displays the data from one of the tables. 

For eg. 

Activity1 would display data from Table1 

Activity2 would display data from Table2 

Activity3 would display data from Table3 and so on

To update respective activity as soon as some data in its corresponding table changes, I have registered a RealmChangeListener with my realm instance. I instantiate Realm in a central class. I don't want to register RealmChangeListener in all the individual classes as registering it once with the central realm instance would be more maintainable.

However, in the onChange callback of the RealmChangeListener, I get the Realm object back and there is no way for me to know that data in which table actually changed.

I am adding the code of how I instantiate realm and register the changeListener below.

MyApplication.java

```
public class MyApplication extends Application{

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        MainClass mainClass = new MainClass(getApplicationContext());
      }
}
```

MainClass.java

```
public class MainClass{
   public MainClass(Context context){
       RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context).build();
       Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(config);
       realm.addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener<Realm>() {
            @Override
            public void onChange(Realm element) {

                //is it possible to know here that data for which table changed?

            }
        });
   }
}
```

My goal is to send a broadcast via LocalBroadcastManager with information regarding which table changed from onChange callback. All the Activities would be listening for this broadcast and if the data in the table associated with the listening activity changed then it would update itself. Rest of the activities would just ignore the broadcast. My aim is to monitor database changes just from one place in my app and send only one Broadcast for a database change. The business logic to deal with the database change will depend on the information contained in the broadcast.

My question would be, is it possible to get notified regarding what table was modified in the RealmChangeListener registered with the global realm? If not, then are there any alternatives to achieve what I want to do?

I am working with:

Realm - 1.0.1
Android Studio - 2.1.2
Min SDK - 19
Target SDK - 23

I am testing my app on android 5.1.1

Thanks for all the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just register a change listener on the relevant RealmResults in your app? Realm is designed so registering change listeners where you need them should be the most frictionless for this type of notifications.

But if you decide to go the LocalBroadcastManager route cannot use the global Realm to detect which tables where changed. You need to register a change listener for on a query that have selected everything in each table in your schema. You can do using the following pattern:

```
    // OnCreate
    DynamicRealm realm = DynamicRealm.getInstance(realmConfig);
    RealmSchema schema = realm.getSchema();
    List<RealmResults<DynamicRealmObject>> strongRefs = new ArrayList<>();
    for (final RealmObjectSchema classSchema : schema.getAll()) {
        // Create a RealmResults for all elements in a Table
        RealmResults<DynamicRealmObject> result = realm.where(classSchema.getClassName()).findAll();
        // Register a changelistener for that realm result
        result.addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<DynamicRealmObject>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChange(RealmResults<DynamicRealmObject> element) {
                Intent intent = new Intent("custom-event-name");
                intent.putExtra("classChanged", classSchema.getClassName());
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
            }
        });
        strongRefs.add(result); // Make sure that RealmResults are not GC'ed
    }


    // onDestroy
    for (RealmResults<DynamicRealmObject> strongRef : strongRefs) {
        strongRef.removeChangeListeners();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Christian Melchior for your prompt reply! I think I will try registering a change listener on the realm results in each activity. However, the second approach also seems interesting. Thanks again for the help.